# jquery insert-before to text in the same DOM

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hi I'm working on inserting a text to this DOM but my try did not work like I expecting.

```
 <p class="doing">Peter are <a href="mysite.com">here</a></p>
<script>$("p.doing").before("I and ");</script>
```

I'm expecting to have result:

```
<p class="doing">I and Peter are <a href="mysite.com">here</a></p>
```

but it was :

```
I and 
<p class="doing">Peter are <a href="mysite.com">here</a></p>
```

Please kindly advise how to solve this.

Comment: ...actually the correct order is 'Peter and I': `$('p.doing').html(  $('p.doing').html() .replace('Peter','Peter and I'));`. If you care about grammar :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use **prepend** instead.

```
$("p.doing").prepend("I and ");
```

Comment: Hi Anthony, That work for me, Thank you so much for great contribution.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(".doing").html('I and '+$(".doing").html());
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the jQuery [prepend()](http://api.jquery.com/prepend/) method:

```
<p class="doing">Peter are <a href="mysite.com">here</a></p>
<script>$(".doing").prepend("I and ");</script>
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/Snowsickle/5havq/)

Answer (score 0):

instead of before, you should use prepend, as before will insert the text into p tag with a class doing.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

</head>
<body>
  <p class="doing">Peter are <a href="mysite.com">here</a></p>
<script>$(".doing").prepend("I and");</script>
</body>
</html>​
```

Comment: This will add the "I and" text before the `<p>` tag - Thanaporn wanted it within the tag.

Comment: @AlexKalicki then he should use prepend as anwered by Anthony. thanks for making me correct, i will edit my answer.